# Lambda capture list: capturing object's member field by value not possible without capturing the whole object?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, language-lawyer

The following code

```
void CMainWindow::someMethod(const CLocationsCollection& parentItem)
{
    auto f = [this, parentItem.displayName](){};
}
```

gives me an error:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ']' before '.'

If I wanted to catch `parentItem.displayName` by ref, I'd make a non-dependent alias identifier for it:

```
const QString& name = parentItem.displayName;
auto f = [this, &name](){}; // Or should it be [this, name] ?
```

But I need to capture it by value, and I don't want to capture the whole `parentItem` because it's heavy. Any solution?

P. S. Names in the capture list must be identifiers. Isn't `parentItem.displayName` (as a whole) an identifier? Why can't it be parsed properly by the compiler?

Comment: [C++14 to the rescue!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd64f0a437929db7)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> <sup>**Note**: All standard references in this post are taken from the C++ Standard Draft [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).</sup>

---

#### Introduction

The standard states that a *capture* must be `&`, `=`, `this`, an *identifier*, or an *identifier* preceeded by `&`.

> `5.1.2` **Lambda expressions** `[expr.prim.lambda]`
>
> > ```
> > capture-list:
> >   capture ..._opt
> >   capture-list , capture ..._opt
> >
> > capture:
> >   identifier
> >   & identifier
> >   this
> > ```

Since `parentItem.displayName` is not an identifier, but a *"class member access expression"*. the compiler is correct when rejecting your snippet.

> `5.2.5p1` **Class member access** `[expr.ref]`
>
> > A postfix expression followed by a dot `.` or an arrow `->`, optionally follow by the keyword `template` (14.2), and then followed by an id-expression, is a postfix expression. The postfix expression before the dot or arrow is evaluated;<sup>66</sup> the result of that evaluation, together with the id-expression, determines the result of the entire postfix expression.

---

#### If only there was a way to initialize captures with *expressions*...

In *C++14* you **will** be able to use an *init-capture* to circumvent the issue at hand, looking as the snippet below. It will create a capture with the name *display_name*, initialized with the value of *parentItem.displayName*.

```
[display_name = parentItem.displayName](){ ... };
```

---

#### What about *C++11*?

Sadly such a feature is not available in *C++11*. The solution to the problem is therefore to make a local reference to the the data-member, and then capture that reference when creating the lambda.

```
auto& lmb_display_name = parentItem.displayName;

[lmb_display_name](){ ... }; // the lambda will have a copy of `parentItem.displayName`
```

<sup>**Note**: Your original post seems to imply that the name of a *reference* *R* in a lambda's capture-list would make the lambda contain a reference to that which *R* refers to, something which isn't true, as can be seen by [this snippet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e2c3304c1f923e3).</sup>

Comment: So even if _identifier_ has reference type, it will still capture the underlying object it refers to by value, as long as this _identifier_ is not preceded by `&` in the capture list?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe exactly.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write a detailed reply with all the explanations.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe it's the only way I know answering questions, I'm glad that it's appreciated!

Comment: Alternatively, you could probably get away with `std::bind([](QString lmb_display_name]{ ... }, parentItem.displayName);`